# C# return value of (int) +=

Tags: c#, syntax

In C#, you can use `int Previous = x++;` to load the value of `x`, before being incremented, into `Previous` (Previous=0, x=1). However, `int Previous = x += 5` does not behave the same way (Previous=5, x=5).

Is there a suitable shorthand statement to increase an integer by an interval larger than 1, while storing the original variable, that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Even if there was, do you really want to have to maintain code that does something like that, rather than just assigning it on the previous line?

Comment: I would suggest that a statement like `int Previous = x++;` is poor form anyway as it is much less obvious and readable than `int Previous = x; x++;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a suitable shorthand statement to increase an integer by an interval larger than 1, while storing the original variable, that I'm unaware of?

No, there's no general compound post-increment operator.

You could fake it with a method if you really want:

```
public static int PostIncrement(ref int variable, int amount)
{
    int original = variable;
    variable += amount;
    return original;
}
```

Then:

```
int previous = PostIncrement(ref x, 5);
```

I would personally try to avoid doing this though, just in terms of readability... I pretty much *always* use compound assignment operators as standalone statements.